# Jquery Switch Arabic fonts

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, arabic

I want to display Arabic on my site.... quite straight forward so far :)

What i would like Jquery to do is to have a button/image which, when clicked,  will toggle the css file and switch between 2 different Arabic fonts ie. simple arabic & uthmani arabic fonts.

does anyone know how this can be done?

regards

Comment: Why do you want to toggle CSS files? Why not use classes instead?

Comment: sounds like a good idea, how does the browser handle the different fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of toggling the CSS file itself, you can associate each font with a [CSS class](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Class_selectors) and toggle that class. For instance:

```
.simple {
    font-family: simplified arabic;
}

.uthmani {
    font-family: uthmantn;
}
```

If you start in simplified arabic mode:

```
<div class="simple">
    العربية
</div>
```

You can remove the `simple` class and add the `uthmani` class in a single call to [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$("div").toggleClass("simple uthmani");
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byveU/).

Comment: Thanks for this, are the simplified arabic and uthmantn fonts default system fonts?, or would i have to install a font from somewhere, how would this work for custom fonts?